# Prevent MS Windows from drawing on secondary monitor

Tags: winapi

I have a scientific instrument that is connected to my computer's graphics card and functions like a monitor. I want to completely define what is displayed on that instrument at all times. Unfortunately, Windows displays all kinds of junk whenever it decides to repaint all monitors and in other cases as well. In 2020, Microsoft announced a Windows Pro/Enterprise feature to "Remove display from desktop", which would stop Windows itself from displaying anything on that monitor, but still allow the programmer to access it from their code. Does anyone know how to do this, programmatically (WinAPI?) or via some trick?

P.S. Currently, I have 2 ways of drawing on my instrument: [SetDIBitsToDevice()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setdibitstodevice) and a PyQt5-window, but I could also program in OpenGL, for example.

Comment: What do you mean by "Windows displays all kinds of junk whenever it decides to repaint all monitors and in other cases as well." If this instrument functions like a monitor, don't blame Windows.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify. I want to be able to program what is displayed and I want the operating system to not touch it in any way. No repainting, no blue screen of death, no monitor numbers from "Identify" monitors, nothing. As long as my program runs, I define the picture with absolute certainty. And no, that is not a useless feature. And yes, there are many applications that need this (scientific instruments, fullscreen displays in the subway and anywhere else, ...) Sorry, I am just too annoyed by WinAPI.

Comment: Possibly you want a [custom compositor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/specialized-monitors-compositor).

Comment: It's the responsibility of the monitor driver to tell Windows how it behaves so it's not part of default DWM composition. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/specialized-monitors it's done with EDID that the driver gives back: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/specialized-monitors-edid-extension you should ask the vendor. Or do it yourself and override EDID https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/overriding-monitor-edids https://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/moninfo.shtm

Comment: I see, thanks so much to both of you. The manufacturer of my instrument is Hamamatsu Photonics and their customer support has been less than helpful about writing a driver. Now I know how it could be done.